# how to show "no result" if received an empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am building a wiki result viewer, and trying to print "No Result" if the json data array is empty. But my code doesn't show it properly. Please see below:

```
form.onsubmit = function() {
  $("#results").html("");
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + form.keyword.value + "&limit=5&namespace=0&format=json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
      results = json[1]
      if (results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < json[1].length; i++) {
          $("#results").append(
            "<div class=\"results\"><div class=\"title\">" + json[1][i] + "</div>" +
            "<div class=\"description\">" + json[2][i] +
            "<a target=\"_blank\"href=\"" + json[3][i] + "\"><div class=\"wikilink\"> Go to article </div></a>" +
            "</div></div>");
        }
      } else {
        $("#results").html("No results");
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Am I missing anything? Thank you so much!

Comment: there is no such thing as  `for(){}else{}`

Comment: the for loop is in the if(result){}. i thought i can put a loop inside?

Comment: sure you can but not the `else` *inside* the `if()`

Comment: yep just fixed it i deleted the closing bracket by accident

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if the result array is empty

```
if (results && results.length > 0)
```

instead

Comment: Or just `if (results && results.length)`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG, could you tell me the difference between `if(result)` and `if(results && results.length)`?  I thought `if(result)` means result=true, which means there is json data i receive.

Comment: @bom if (results) will execute if results is not null, false, undefined, or 0. In this case result is not null (empty array). The same with results.length. Because it is confusing. So I think checking > 0 is better. If you are confident that your service always returns an array if (results.length > 0) is enough.

Comment: @bom—yes, but you want to know if *results* has any elements. So testing *results* makes sure there's a non–falsey value, then *results.length* tests if it has a non–falsey length value (e.g. not zero). You need both tests in case *results* is, say, *null* in which case *results.length* will throw an error. As Daniel says, if you are certain that *results* will always be an array, then *results.length* is sufficient.